# Incorrect order of output Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok , now i got my output but , everything doesnt seem to be in order. I tried for days and nights. Now I understand more about Multi Threading. How do i get the output as what i expected ? Can someone advise me which part did I do wrongly ?

This is my Test program

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{

public static void main (String[]args)
{
int totalShares = 0;
double totalCost = 0.0;
double totalProfitLoss = 0.0; 
int rand1 = 0;
double rand2 = 0.0;
Stock stock = new Stock("FCS",totalShares,totalCost,totalProfitLoss);

System.out.println ("Tracking of stock:  " +stock.name);
BuyThread bt = new BuyThread (rand1 , rand2 , stock);
SellThread st = new SellThread (rand1 , rand2 , stock);
bt.start();
st.start();

try
{
bt.join();
st.join();


System.out.println ("At$ 36.00 per share, profit is " + stock.getProfit(36.00));
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
```

This is my Stock Class

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stock
{
String name;
int totalShares;
double totalCost; 
double totalProfitLoss;


public Stock(String name, int totalShares, double totalCost,double totalProfitLoss )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.totalShares = totalShares;
    this.totalCost = totalCost;
    this.totalProfitLoss = totalProfitLoss;
} 

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public double getTotalShares () 
{
    //totalShares++;
    return totalShares;
}
public double getTotalCost () 
{
   // totalCost++;
    return totalCost;
}
public double getTotalProfitLoss() 
{

    return totalProfitLoss;
}



public void buy(int shares, double pricePerShare)
{
    totalShares += shares;
    totalCost += shares * pricePerShare;
    System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ " +totalCost);

}

public boolean sell(int shares, double pricePerShare) 
{
  double sellCost = shares * pricePerShare;


  if (shares >= totalShares || sellCost >= totalCost){

      return false;

    }
    else {
      totalShares -= shares;
      totalCost -= sellCost;

      System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ "+totalCost);   

        return true;

    }

}

public double getProfit (double currentPrice)
{
    totalProfitLoss = currentPrice * totalShares;
    return totalProfitLoss - totalCost;
}

}
```

This is my BuyThread program

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class BuyThread extends Thread
{
private int rand1 ;
private double rand2;
private Stock stock;

public BuyThread (int rand1,double rand2,Stock stock)
{
this.rand1 = rand1 ;
this.rand2 = rand2 ;
this.stock = stock;
}

public void run()
{
for (int j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
{
Random randShare = new Random ();
int rand1 = randShare.nextInt (50) + 5 ;
double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10 + 32)* 100.0)/100.0 ;

stock.buy (rand1, rand2);
System.out.println (rand1+ " shares has been brought at $"+rand2) ;


try
{ sleep (50);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
}
```

This is my SellThread

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class SellThread extends Thread
{
private int rand1 ;
private double rand2;
private Stock stock;

public SellThread (int rand1,double rand2,Stock stock)
{
this.rand1 = rand1 ;
this.rand2 = rand2 ;
this.stock = stock;
}

public void run()
{
for (int j = 0 ; j < 2; j++)
{
Random randShare = new Random ();
int rand1 = randShare.nextInt (20) + 20 ;
double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 32 + 23)* 100.0)/100.0 ;

stock.sell (rand1 , rand2);
System.out.println (rand1+" shares has been sold at $"+rand2) ;


try
{
Thread.sleep(30);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{}
}
}
}
```

I got this output :

```
Tracking of stock:  FCS
Sell Total shares now at 13 at total cost $ 381.0999999999997
Buy Total shares now at 50 at total cost $ 1664.9999999999998
37 shares has been sold at $34.7
50 shares has been brought at $33.3
32 shares has been sold at $51.97
Buy Total shares now at 18 at total cost $ 555.1499999999996
5 shares has been brought at $34.81
At$ 36.00 per share, profit is 92.85000000000036
```

I am expecting a output :

```
Tracking of Stock : FCS
8 shares has been brought at $37.61
Total shares now 8 at total cost $300.88
33 shares has been brought at $36.31
Total shares now 41 at total cost $1499.11  
17 shares has been sold at $42.67
Total shares now 24 at total cost $773.72
19 shares has been sold at $32.31
Total shares now 5 at total cost $159.83
31 shares has been brought at $33.85
Total shares now 36 at total cost $1209.18
28 shares has been brought at $36.37
Total shares now 64 at total cost $2227.54
20 shares has been brought at $35.49
Total shares now 84 at total cost $2937.34
At $36.00 per share, profit is $86.66
```

Comment: double rand2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 32 + 23)* 100.0)/100.0 ; maybe (int) destroys the randomization maybe being 32 not 32.0

Comment: There is no such thing as *Ordering* in a threaded environment, it is by definition **non-deterministic**, your expectations are wrong!

Comment: Hi, how do I write a proper Random double with 2 decimal point within a range?

Answer (score 0):

use wait and notify with synchronized

wait makes the thread to be wait and notify awake up other waiting thread.

please fill the condition to be waiting state and same for notify condition.

```
synchronized public void buy(int shares, double pricePerShare)
    {
        if(totalShares>0)
        {
          wait();
        }
        totalShares += shares;
        totalCost += shares * pricePerShare;
        System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ " +totalCost);
        notify();
    }

    synchronized public void sell(int shares, double pricePerShare) 
    {
      double sellCost = shares * pricePerShare;


        if (shares >= totalShares || sellCost >= totalCost)
        {
         wait();
        }
        else 
        {
          totalShares -= shares;
          totalCost -= sellCost;
          System.out.println ("Total shares now at " +totalShares+ " at total cost $ "+totalCost);   
          notify();
        }

    }
```